# Using interface and base class for independent "modules"

Tags: c#, interface, module, subclass, abstract

I have a question on how to use interfaces and abstract classes the right way in my C# program. I have many "modules" which are independent (BeatsPerMinuteMeasurement, MouseRecorder, ClipboardHistory etc.). All of them have at least a Panel (UserControl) and a "Logic" (normal Class). First, there was no inheritance. But now I'm rewriting it like this: (->) means inheritance from:

- SomeLogic -> BaseLogic -> IBaseLogic
- SomePanel -> BasePanel -> UserControl, IBasePanel

The question: is that a good way to do it? Here is my panel-code (which is not working because of strange inheritance errors):

```
interface IBasePanel {
    void RegisterEvents();
    void Close();
}

abstract class BasePanel : UserControl, IBasePanel  {
    public BasePanel() {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterEvents(); //Compiler error, compiler cant find it
    }

    public abstract void InitializeComponent(); 
}

class MouseKeyRecord_Panel : BasePanel {
    //GUI variables (buttons/labels etc.)

    public MouseKeyRecord_Panel() {

    }

    protected override void RegisterEvents() {
        //Register EventHandler for buttons etc.
    }

    protected override void InitializeComponent() {
        //Visual Studio auto generated GUI
    }

    public override void Close() {
        //Closing Threads etc.
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**
Solved.
I deleted the interface and it's working now. I guess I used interfaces the wrong way. I still don't know when to use abstract classes and when to use interfaces.

Comment: If you have no inheritance, why would you want to start doing it? Is it not working currently? Whatever you are trying to achieve can always be better solved with composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: well, it worked, but i want to redesign them to make it "better".all of them have a few things in common. they all have a Close,InitializeComponent and RegisterEvents method. i learned it this way: if you see that classes have the same methods, use a base class so every class that needs that method can inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler error occurs because, as the compiler stated, the required implementations of `RegisterEvents()` and `Close()` did not appear in your `BaseClass` implementation.

If you want to defer implementation to subclasses, then the right way to implement the interface in the base class is to declared `abstract` implementations, just as you did for `InitializeComponent()`:

```
abstract class BasePanel : UserControl, IBasePanel  {
    public BasePanel() {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterEvents();
    }

    public abstract void InitializeComponent(); 
    public abstract void RegisterEvents();
    public abstract void Close();
}
```

That said, note that simply making the above change wouldn't get the code you posted to compile. Implicitly-implemented interfaces must be implemented using `public` members. You can't make `RegisterEvents()` a `protected` member. On the other hand, if you actually want it to be a `protected` member, then it probably should not be in an interface, since by design members of an interface are intended to be public.

Along those same lines, you also have a problem with the `InitializeComponent()` method, which you've declared in the base class as `public`, but in the derived `MouseKeyRecord_Panel` class as `protected`. You cannot change the accessibility on an override of a virtual member. Either make the override a `public` method, or change the base class declaration to `protected`.

It may well be true that you still don't know when to use abstract classes and interfaces. But the first step is knowing *how*. :) As for the "when", the short answer is that abstract classes and interfaces are very similar; the main exception is that an abstract class can (and generally does) include some actual implementation in addition to the interface declared (i.e. the `abstract` members of an abstract class are effectively the interface declared by that class…note that unlike interfaces, `abstract` members of an abstract class aren't required to be `public`).

Also, of course being an actual class, any given type can inherit at most one abstract class (and none, if it already is inheriting some other class). You can *implement* as many interfaces as you want/need (some people describe this as also inheriting an interface, but I tend to think of inheriting implementations, and implementing interfaces).

Any explanation more in-depth than that is IMHO too broad for Stack Overflow and best left to the many resources available in text books, blogs, and other articles on the web (including the C# documentation on MSDN).